# How does the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process work, and how it is used in DDPG?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, policy-gradients, papers, ddpg

In section 3 of the paper [Continuous control with deep reinforcement learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971.pdf), the authors write

> As detailed in the supplementary materials we used an **Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process** (Uhlenbeck & Ornstein, 1930) to generate temporally correlated exploration for exploration efficiency in physical control problems with inertia (similar use of autocorrelated noise was introduced in (Wawrzynski, 2015)).

In section 7, they write

> For the exploration noise process we used temporally correlated noise in order to explore well in physical environments that have momentum. We used an **Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process** (Uhlenbeck & Ornstein, 1930) with θ = 0.15 and σ = 0.2. The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process models the velocity of a Brownian particle with friction, which results in temporally correlated values centered around 0.

In a few words, what is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process? How does it work? How exactly is it used in DDPG?

I want to implement the Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient algorithm, and, in the initial actions, noise has to be added. However, I cannot understand how this Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process works. I have searched the internet, but I have not understood the information that I found.

Comment: It should be noted that more recent work suggests that uncorrelated Gaussian noise works just as well.
TD3 paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09477.pdf): "Unlike the original DDPG, we used uncorrelated noise for exploration as we found noise drawn from the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (Uhlenbeck & Ornstein, 1930) process offered no performance benefits."
D4PG paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.08617.pdf): "We experimented with correlated noise drawn from an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, as suggested by (Lillicrap et al., 2016), however we found this was unnecessary and did not add to performance."

Answer (score 6):

The Ornstein Ulhenebck Process is defined as (in the continuous setting) :

$$dX_t = -\beta(X_t - \alpha)dt + \sigma dW_t$$

The analogue for this process in the discrete time case which I assume will be applicable in the RL case will be:
$$X_{t+1} = X_t -\beta(X_t - \alpha) + \sigma \{W_{t+1}-W_t\}=$$
$$X_{t+1} = (1 -\beta)X_t + \alpha\beta + \sigma \{W_{t+1}-W_t\}$$

In the RL seting the terms in the equation probably means:

- $X_t$ will stand for a state in RL i.e. the state is the number $\in \mathbb R$ where the particle moves to at time $t$.
- $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are just constants which decide certain movement characteristics of the particle. Check [here](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Esusanne/StatDiff/Overheads1b) for graphs plotted for various $\beta$.
- $W_t$ is a [Weiner process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) which starts at $W_0 = 0$ and then adds **independent** increments of $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma)$ as $W_{t+1} = W_t+\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma)$ which is basically a radom walk. More generally we use $\mathcal N(0,1)$. This is formulated as $W_t-W_s = \sqrt{t-s} \mathcal N(0,1)$. This is because of the fact, $W_t$ can be written recursively as $W_t = \mathcal N(0,1)+W_{t-1} = \mathcal N(0,1) + \mathcal N(0,1) + ...W_s$ and since the samplings are independent at each step the **mean** get added as $\mu_t+\mu_{t-1}...$ and the **variances** as $\sigma_t^2 + \sigma_{t-1}^2...$. SInce her the means and variances are $0$ and $1$ respectively, the final mean $\mu = 0$ and variance $\sigma^2 = (t-s)$. And hence, byproperties of Gaussian random variables you can write (it is easy to show this via variable tranformation) $W_t-W_s = \sqrt{t-s} \mathcal N(0,1)$.  [Here](https://sites.me.ucsb.edu/%7Emoehlis/APC591/tutorials/tutorial7/node2.html), is the formulation of standard Weiner process.
- $\sigma$ will be the weighting factor of the Weiner process, which just  means the amount of noise being added to the process.

Another useful [resource](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3214&context=etd) on discrete Ornstein Ulhenbeck process, much less generalized.
I think now you can extend this to whatever scenario you are intereted in RL setting.